# How do I simultaneously animate a UIImageView's image and the UIImageView itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

The title may not be so clear, but what I want to do is to make the UIImageView display a series of images (sort of like a gif) and I do this by setting the `animationImages` to an array of images and then calling `[imageView startAnimating];`. This works fine. I also have code that moves the UIImageView around with a CABasicAnimation, and this animation code also works fine. However, when I try to both animate the images of the UIImageView and try to move the UIImageView around, the images of the UIImageView stop animating. Is there a workaround?

Here's my code for animating the content of the UIImageView:

```
    self.playerSprite = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.player.animationImages objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.playerSprite setFrame:CGRectMake(self.center.x, self.center.y, self.tileSet.constants.TILE_WIDTH, self.tileSet.constants.TILE_HEIGHT)];
    self.playerSprite.animationImages = self.player.animationImages;
    self.playerSprite.animationDuration = self.tileSet.constants.animationDuration;
    self.playerSprite.animationRepeatCount = 0; //Makes it repeat indefinitely
```

And here's my coding for animating the UIImageView with a CABasicAnimation:

```
float playerSpriteX = self.playerSprite.center.x;
float playerSpriteY = self.playerSprite.center.y;

CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
moveAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(playerSpriteX + TILE_WIDTH, playerSpriteY)];
[moveAnimation setDelegate:self];
[moveAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[moveAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[moveAnimation setDuration:MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION];       
[self.playerSprite.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

So the gif effect isn't working while the UIImageView's position is being animated. My question is **how can I make it so the UIImageView cycles through an array of images while its position is being animated?**

Comment: Added some detail and an illustrative video to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is speculation and I haven't tested this idea at all, but have you considered implementing the image animation in the same fashion you're animating the position, with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`? You'd need to construct an array of `CGImage` objects from your `UIImage` array (to set the `values` property of the keyframe animation) but it looks like a pretty straightforward conversion:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *imageAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
imageAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete; // or maybe kCAAnimationPaced
imageAnimation.duration = self.tileSet.constants.animationDuration;
imageAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
// the following method will need to be implemented to cast your UIImage array to CGImages
imageAnimation.values = [self animationCGImagesArray];
[self.playerSprite.layer addAnimation:imageAnimation forKey:@"contents"];

-(NSArray*)animationCGImagesArray {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.player.animationImages count]];
    for (UIImage *image in self.player.animationImages) {
        [array addObject:(id)[image CGImage]];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

Comment: How do I store an array of CGImage objects in an array though? Do I just cast them to `(id)`?

Comment: Yes.  And you can get a `CGImage` from a `UIImage` with `[myImage CGImage]`.

Comment: I agree so strongly with this approach that I have completely rewritten my own answer!

Comment: This example did not work for me. Adding the keyframe animation to a uiimageview with UIimages from the asset catalog, then calling startanimation does not change the initial image

Comment: @SeamusCampbell

Code crashes if we have more images (300 images of 720*720 having 60Kb size of each ), Any alternate or idea ??
Because adding images to array will allocate lot of memory hence Memory Crash !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've just done something similar.  The code I used looks like this:

```
    CGRect r = ziv.frame;
    r.origin.x += WrongDistance;
    [ziv startAnimating];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^(void){
        [ziv setFrame:r];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [ziv stopAnimating];

        if (finished){
            // not canceled in flight
            if (NumWrong == MaxWrong)
                [self endOfGame:NO];
            else
                [self nextRound:self];
        }
    }];
```

Perhaps the issue you're running into is because both animations are on the same thread?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to make a sprite. I could insist that you should be using OpenGL, but there may be no need to go that far; you can do it all with Core Animation of a layer, and I think you'll be better off doing that than trying to use a full-fledged UIImageView.

Using Core Animation of a layer, I was able to make this PacMan sprite animate across the screen while opening and closing his mouth; isn't that the sort of thing you had in mind?

[image]

Here is a video showing the animation!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXCLc9ww8MI

And yet the actual code creating the animation is extremely simple: just two layer animations (Core Animation), one for the changing image, the other for the position.

**You should *not* award this answer the bounty! I am now merely echoing what Seamus Campbell said; I'm just filling out the details of his answer a little.**

Okay, so here's the code that generates the movie linked above:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // construct arr, an array of CGImage (omitted)
    // it happens I've got 5 images, the last being the same as the first
    self.images = [arr copy];
    // place sprite into the interface
    self.sprite = [CALayer new];
    self.sprite.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,24,24);
    self.sprite.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.sprite];
    self.sprite.contents = self.images[0];
}

- (void)animate {
    CAKeyframeAnimation* anim = 
        [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    anim.values = self.images;
    anim.keyTimes = @[@0,@0.25,@0.5,@0.75,@1];
    anim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
    anim.duration = 1.5;
    anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    CABasicAnimation* anim2 = 
        [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anim2.duration = 10;
    anim2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(350,30)];

    CAAnimationGroup* group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.animations = @[anim, anim2];
    group.duration = 10;

    [self.sprite addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I unaccepted. I tried to follow the link (which initially looked promising) but I couldn't do it. I'll try out your new code though. Thanks!

Comment: Just a question: what is the "index" property of CALayer?

Comment: It's just like the `sampleIndex` property in the tutorial I pointed to. Basically, as the `index` changes, the CALayer subclass responds by redrawing with the next image in the sequence.

Comment: I've now provided even more elaborate code, differing quite significantly from the original tutorial.

Comment: Revising again, this time without the sprite layer subclass.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you're putting into this. I was looking at the code and wondering where exactly the animation between images is taking place.

Comment: Okay. Anyway, thanks for all the help you've given me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I really enjoyed playing, and making my little PacMan example!

Answer (score 1):

Your "basic" problem starts on this line:

```
CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
```

A `CABasicAnimation` object [uses only a single keyframe](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CABasicAnimation). That means that the content of the layer that you're animating is drawn once, and then that image is used for the duration of the animation.

Using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` as Seamus suggests is one way to deal with the problem -- a keyframe animation will redraw the content of the animated layer multiple times, so drawing successive images for each keyframe will animate the content as well as position.